# Passing an array from one function to another in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a function that generates two arrays (`X` and `Y`).

I would like to do some calculations with both arrays inside this function by passing this array to another function `BETA`. Both functions work perfectly on their own. I don't know how to pass the array correctly to the function `BETA`. Here's the code for the inner function:

```
Function BETA(ByRef X As Range, ByRef Y As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim B As Double
    Dim X_SUM As Double, Y_SUM As Double
    Dim X_MEAN As Double, Y_MEAN As Double

    X_MEAN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(X)
    Y_MEAN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Y)


    For i = 1 To UBound(X)

      X(i) = X(i) - X_MEAN
      Y(i) = Y(i) - Y_MEAN

    Next i

    X_SUM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(X)
    Y_SUM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Y)

    B = (X_SUM * Y_SUM) / (X_SUM) ^ 2


    BETA = B                    
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see an Array? Do you mean passing a Range by any chance?

Comment: if you want to return an object from a function you need to use the `Set` keyword when returning. So `Set BETA = X_SUM` try that

Comment: What exact problem are you experiancing? Are there any errors? If so what are they and what lines?

Answer (score 0):

Several small points:

1. **X** and **Y** are declared as Ranges in the function header, but used as arrays in the function body by the use of **Ubound()**
2. The function calculates **B**, but never exposes it.  Did you intend **`BETA=B`** as the return??
3. **BETA** should be declared as Double rather than Variant in the function header.
4. Did you really intend to modify the function inputs within the body of the function??

Comment: I am new to VBA and therefore very sorry for expressing myself incorrectly... I intended BETA=B, sry for that. The function BETA is used within another function which generates X and Y, where X and Y are Doubles with multiple entries, such as X=(X1, X2, X3 , ...). I do intend to use X and Y as Inputs for caluclating BETA=B. I do not want to modify X and Y.  I'm sry for any confusion